# Interpreting equation from article with Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, random, noise

I was just reading an article in which the authors simulate an equation with added noise based on an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process. This is the equation:

[image]

They describe the term $ n(t) $ in equation A1:

[image]

I would like to reproduce this equation, but don't entirely understand what the authors did there.

Firstly, this does not look to me like the definition of an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process (at least as far as I know)

Secondly, can somebody explain to me, what this last term (angle brackets, representing the white noise process) means? I know angle brackets from the inner product or Expectation values and it seems to me like a DiracDelta impulse at time $ t'$, but I don't understand what this $ t'$ means.

To whom this makes more sense, any help appreciated ;)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, the stochastic equation of the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process is often rewriten as a Langevin equation in physical sciences, which is done here (see e.g. [[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process)]). For the second part, $\left< \xi (t)\xi (t')\right>$ denotes the autocorrelation function of a stationnary random process (here, a white noise). By definition of white noise, the later is a Dirac delta, since its Fourier transform -- the power spectral density -- is constant (see e.g. [[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density#Power_spectral_density)]). The notation with brackets for expected values can be found in quantum physics.

Comment: Thank you, Harry, that makes much more sense now!